# nginx client_max_body_size per http method

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I'm trying to setup nginx to separate client_max_body_size in one location per http method, but client_max_body_size isn't working with "if" and "limit_except":

1) Config:

```
location /test {
   limit_except POST {
      client_max_body_size 1g;
   }
   proxy_pass ...
}
```

nginx -s reload:

```
nginx: [emerg] "client_max_body_size" directive is not allowed here
```

2) Config:

```
location /test {
   if ($request_method !~* POST) {
      client_max_body_size 1g;
   }
   proxy_pass ...
}
```

I get the same message on reload.

How can I set client_max_body_size per http method?

Comment: IMHO it's impossible. `client_max_body_size` does not support variables either. Bummer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can solve this by defining an `upstream` and use `proxy_pass` to redirect at the right condition:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html